# Защита от переворачивания устройства

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Ребята подскажите плагин или код который при переворачивании устройства выведит блок на весь экран с текстом переверните устройство

Comment: [Попробуйте сделать сами](https://nikitakiselev.ru/article/otslezhivanie-izmeneniya-orientacii-na-mobilnyh-ustroystvah-s-pomoshchyu-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

1. Сделайте ваш красивый блок с просьбой сменить ориентацию устройства (чтобы он был всегда на весь экран и фиксированный, ну или как у вас по дизайну ).
2. Дайте ему `display:none` по умолчанию.
3. Давайте `display:block` при нужной ориентации устройства 

   `@media screen and (orientation:portrait) { … }
   @media screen and (orientation:landscape) { … }`

https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#orientation